# How to check and uncheck a checkbox using automated UI testing in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, automated-tests, ui-testing

I want to write a automated UI testing for Xamarin.Form project where I have to Check multiple values in a CheckBox. I have tried using app.Repl() and tree method still I am not getting any solution. Please anyone can Help me out. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You just have to tap it right? `app.Tap(c => c.Marked("MyCheckbox"));` or am I not getting you?

Comment: Thank you Gerald Versluis for your reply but I want to select multiple values . I should tap the box icon for different different values so how to do that?

Comment: What is a checkbox according to you? A checkbox does not have multiple values?

Comment: You should just be able to repeat Geralds piece of code for each checkbox you want to check as far as I know.

Comment: I have a custom Checkbox were tapping on box icon only I can select the value. No Taping on checkbox value will give any desired result.
As far I got to knw from Geralds piece of code he is Tapping the checkbox list value .